# Can I use MPI_Bcast to synchronize?

Tags: mpi

I need to perform an operation that can be performed only by the master process. The slaves can't really do anything but wait for the master to finish. I therefore did the following (pseudocode, I wrap most routines, so I would have a hard time coming up with the actual MPI code. I hope the comments are clear enough in explaining what I am doing)

```
def routine():

    if not isMaster(): 
        # I am a slave. I just sit here, waiting for the master to finish.
        # wait for a string from the master explaining the state
        string = MPI_Bcast("whatever", 0) 
        return (string == "SUCCESS")

    <master does its long running business>

    string = MPI_Bcast("SUCCESS", 0) # tell the slaves it worked fine.

    return True
```

Does this work, or am I misusing the broadcast?

Comment: Just make sure that the root rank in `MPI_Bcast` matches the one used in the `isMaster()` predicate.

Answer (score 2):

If you make that pseudocode:

```
def routine():

    if not isMaster(): 
        # I am a slave. I just sit here, waiting for the master to finish.
        # wait for a string from the master explaining the state
        string = MPI_Bcast("whatever", 0) 
        return (string == "SUCCESS")

    else:
        <master does its long running business>
        string = MPI_Bcast("SUCCESS", 0) # tell the slaves it worked fine.

    return True
```

Then you should be fine. (Of course you need to make sure to get the specific MPI API for your language correct.) In general for a broadcast or any collective operation, each rank in the communicator needs to execute the same number of calls. For understanding, it may be beneficial to restructure the program in a way to unconditionally execute the Bcast for each rank on the same source code line, e.g.

```
def routine():
    status_code = UNKNOWN
    if isMaster(): 
        #do stuff
        status_code = OK

    MPI_Bcast(&status_code, 0)
    #check status_code on each rank
```

Comment: Ok. The point is that it does not matter if the master and the slave don't hit _the_same_call_ to MPI_Bcast. They can be two different calls, but it's good practice that it is the same. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Since there is a `return` statement at the end of the non-master code in the OP, I don't see the point in adding the `else:`. The refactored version is indeed better.